# Empirical density function with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Here is how I can get the empirical density function for 1000 samples of a random variable:

```
X = np.random.normal(0,1,1000)
A = np.zeros(len(X))

for i, j in enumerate(np.linspace(-5,5,100)):
    A[i] = sum(abs(X-j) < 0.1) * 1.0 / len(X)
    print A[i]
```

*(It's even possible to plot it but this is not my primary interest, I'm really interested for the numerical results.)*

I've noticed it's really slow when ~ 1 million of samples.

**Is there a more efficient / more *numpythonic* way to do it ?**

Answer (score 4):

You could leverage [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) after extending `X` to a `2D` shape with [`np.newaxis/None`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) and then performing the same operations, like so  -

```
J = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
Aout = (np.abs(X[:,None] - J) < 0.1).sum(0) * 1.0 / len(X)
```

Comment: Very cool, thanks! I just saw `np.histogram(X)` as well, do you think it could also work for this?

Comment: @Basj Ah yes if you are dealing with such a `J` that has equidistant elements that could be a much better solution! I assumed a general case in  my solution :)

Comment: Would you have an example @Divakar with `np.histogram(X)` that would allow to get the density of the distribution for each point of `np.linspace(-5,5,100)` ? `np.histogram(X)` seems to give 2 arrays, and I don't really what to do with them

Comment: Something else @Divakar, for `X` of length ~ 500 000 elements, I can't use your solution with `J = np.linspace(-50,50,1000)` : `MemoryError`. But still I would like to have density function with at least 1000 points. Any idea?

Comment: @Basj Well as an after-thought since you are getting absolute differences, `np.histogram` might not work I think. Also, if you are working with such huge datasizes, you might as well keep the loop that you have as it's just `1000` elements.

Comment: The absolute value only means I want to count the number of elements `x_k` such that for example `abs(x_k - 3) <= 0.1` i.e. nothing else than **x_k is in the bin [2.9, 3.1]**. Isn't this possible with histogram?

Comment: @Basj Ah yes, that's the idea! In theory, seems plausible then.

Answer (score 0):

This solves the problem:

```
X = np.random.normal(0,1,1000)
hist, bins = np.histogram(X, bins=np.linspace(-5,5,100), density=True)
```